# Visualforce charting barseries not showing the bars

Tags: visualforce-charting

I have copied the code from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_overview_providing_data_controller_method.htm and haven't changed anything. But the bars don't show in my Visualforce page. Here is how it looks:
[image]

As you can see, the bar bars don't show. And in the datatable, the data seem to be valid. And I changed the VF page code to use a pieseries instead and it shows successfully. Any suggestions why it is not working?

Answer (score 5):

Just figured out what is happening here. There is a mistake with the example: it should be xField="Amount" yField="Name". The example reversed it. Changed the code and works for me now.